# Issue using formula on PHPExcel (Excel2007)

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

When I try to set the value of an cell with a formula, e.g.: setCellValue('C1', '=A1+B1'), the generated file don't have the calculated value for the cells.

I have the following script:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 5)
    ->setCellValue('B1', 10)
    ->setCellValue('C1', '=A1+B1');
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C1')->getCalculatedValue() . PHP_EOL;

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('a.xlsx');
```

When I open a.xlsx with libreoffice, the cell C1 shows the string "0". The odd thing is that when I click the cell it actually shows "=A1+B1", but not the final result.

How do I get PHPExcel to work with formulas properly?

Comment: What version of LibreOffice?

Comment: LibreOffice 4.2.4.2 420(Build:2)

Comment: This may well require a patch to PHPExcel.... I know it's worked correctly with some versions of LibreOffice, but I'll need to do some testing.... may take a couple of days

Comment: I tried opening on Office 2013. After I click on the enable editing button, it calculates the cell C1. I thought the problem was with the way I was using PHPExcel, but it might be something related to LibreOffice, as you've suggested.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with LibreOffice 4.2.8.2. Did you find any way to solve this problem? The same XLSX file, opened with Excel 2010 works without any problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, @mHouses, it has been a long time ago and, as far as I remember, I didn't solve that issue. I probably worked around it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with LibreOffice 5.0.5.2.

Changing the following option in LibreOffice Calc worked for me:

- Go to Tools/Options.../LibreOffice Calc/Formula
- In section "Recalculation on file load", "Excel 2007 and newer", change the value to "Always recalculate"

Found on 
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12165/calc-auto-recalc-does-not-work/